# how to get file extension from url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a js file downloader module. Right now I stumbled on some file urls like - https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA_Rg2GwJVJEmOGGoYFev_eTSZAjkp_stpi4cUXpjWbE6Wh7gSpCvldg.

My question here is how to get the proper extension of the file knowing only the url ?

The only idea I have is to use this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to check the file after I download it.

Comment: Look at its `content-type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @melpomene you can make `HEAD` request for file, get `Content-Type` from response headers

```js
fetch("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA_Rg2GwJVJEmOGGoYFev_eTSZAjkp_stpi4cUXpjWbE6Wh7gSpCvldg", {method:"HEAD"})
.then(response => response.headers.get("Content-Type"))
.then(type => console.log(`.${type.replace(/.+\/|;.+/g, "")}`));
```